# How to replace a string in a file using jenkins pipeline script

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to edit a file package.json and trying to replace a string("version:1") inside it using jenkins pipeline script. I have written below script but its not working.

```
def readContent = readFile './package.json'

updatedProp = readContent.replaceAll("version:.*","version:${env.ReleaseNumber}.${BUILD_NUMBER},")
 
writeFile file: './package.json', text: "${updatedProp}"
```

package.json file contains below content.

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I request to correct me and help me building the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code.

```
def data = readJSON file: 'package.json'
String val = "${ReleaseNumber}"
data['version'] = val
writeJSON file: 'package.json', json: data,  overwrite: true
```

**Update with prettyfy**

You will have to import JsonOutput hence add `import groovy.json.JsonOutput` before the pipeline.

```
def data = readJSON file: 'package.json'
String val = "${ReleaseNumber}"
data['version'] = val
def formtted = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(data))
writeFile file: 'package.json', text: formtted,  overwrite: true
```

Comment: This is working as expected but all the lines in package.json is becoming as single line. Can you please suggest to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

***Jenkins*** plugin **Content Replace** can also be used with regular expressions like this

```
contentReplace(
  configs: [
    fileContentReplaceConfig(
      configs: [
        fileContentReplaceItemConfig(
          search: '(Version=)([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)',
          replace: '$11.0.${BUILD_ID}',
          matchCount: 1,
          verbose: false,
        )
      ],
      fileEncoding: 'UTF-8',
       'versions.txt'
    )
  ]
)
```